# UIImageView Gestures (Zoom, Rotate) Question

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, zooming, rotation, pinch

I would like to make 2 operations to an `UIImageView` zoom, rotate, I have 2 problems:

> **A.** I make an operation for zoom for ex. and when I try to make rotation the `UIImageView` is set to initial size, I would like to know how to keep the zoomed `UIImageView` and make the rotation from the zoomed image.
>
> **B.** I would like to combine the zoom operation with rotation and I don't know ho to implement this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    foo = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 600, 800.0)];
    foo.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    foo.multipleTouchEnabled  = YES;
    foo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"earth.jpg"];
    foo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    foo.clipsToBounds = YES;
    
    [self.view addSubview:foo];
}

//---pinch gesture--- 
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture =
[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
[foo addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture]; 
[pinchGesture release];

//---rotate gesture--- 
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateGesture =
[[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotateGesture:)];
[foo addGestureRecognizer:rotateGesture]; 
[rotateGesture release];

//---handle pinch gesture--- 
-(IBAction) handlePinchGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    NSLog(@"Pinch");
    CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) sender scale];
    if (factor > 1) { 
        //---zooming in--- 
        sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(
                                                           lastScaleFactor + (factor-1),
                                                           lastScaleFactor + (factor-1)); 
    } 
    else {
        //---zooming out--- 
        sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor * factor, lastScaleFactor * factor);
    }
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) { 
        if (factor > 1) {
            lastScaleFactor += (factor-1); 
        } else {
            lastScaleFactor *= factor;
        }
    }
}

//---handle rotate gesture--- 
-(IBAction) handleRotateGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    CGFloat rotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) sender rotation]; 
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation + netRotation); 
    sender.view.transform = transform;
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) { 
        netRotation += rotation;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i am trying to set the pinch zoom on my app can you just tell me what is lastScaleFactor in your code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 64):

Hope this can be helpful to you, that's how I usually implement gesture recognizers:

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
[piece addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];
[rotationGesture release];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scalePiece:)];
[pinchGesture setDelegate:self];
[piece addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
[pinchGesture release];
```

Rotate method: Reset the gesture recognizer's rotation to 0 after applying so the next callback is a delta from the current rotation

```
- (void)rotatePiece:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }
}
```

Scale Method, at the end reset the gesture recognizer's scale to 1 after applying so the next callback is a delta from the current scale

```
- (void)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
[self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }
}
```

Than ensure that the pinch, pan and rotate gesture recognizers on a particular view can all recognize simultaneously prevent other gesture recognizers from recognizing simultaneously

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
// if the gesture recognizers are on different views, don't allow simultaneous recognition
if (gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view)
    return NO;

// if either of the gesture recognizers is the long press, don't allow simultaneous recognition
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] || [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
    return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Scale and rotation transforms are applied relative to the layer's anchor point this method moves a gesture recognizer's view's anchor point between the user's fingers

```
- (void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
        CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];

        piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
        piece.center = locationInSuperview;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Just implement [gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) in your delegate.

I have a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` set up and I want them all to work at the same time. I also have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` which I do **not** want to be recognized simultaneously. All I did was this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] && ![otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I found something that may interest you on the **stanford university** website:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-winter

on this site you will need to scroll down until you see the number 14: "**Title: Lecture #14 - MultiTouch"**

Download the: **"14_MultiTouchDemo.zip"**

In this example you can scale and rotate every image at the same time.

hope i helped :)

Comment: This demo doesn't use UIGestureRecognizer, it resolves the the touches meaning.

Answer (score 3):

When you use CGAffineTransformMakeScale, you are resetting the transformation of Identity every time you use it and you lose the previous transformation information.

Try using `CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,scale, scale)` for the pinch zooming. You will need to retain the original frame size to keep the zooming under control though.
see: [How can I use pinch zoom(UIPinchGestureRecognizer) to change width of a UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691369/how-can-i-use-pinch-zoomuipinchgesturerecognizer-to-change-width-of-a-uitextvie/2861434#2861434)

For rotation similarly:

```
   if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([view transform], [gestureRecognizer rotation]);
        [gestureRecognizer setRotation:0];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a pretty old thread, I came across this imageview subclass, which works nice for zoom, rotate and pan. It uses gesture recognizer on an imageview. I am using this for one of my app.

[ZoomRotatePanImageView](https://github.com/bennythemink/ZoomRotatePanImageView)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.