# fullscreen image pinching ipad

Tags: image, ipad, fullscreen, uigesturerecognizer, pinch

can someone tell me plz if it's possible to use : `UIGestureRecognizer` on an image in ipad app to switch this image to fullscreen view when pinching in and back to the original size when pinching out? any sample of code will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To hide navigation bar use -

```
[[self navigationController ] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

see my this answer to hide tabbar -

[How to hide uitabbarcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272290/how-to-hide-uitabbarcontroller/5272497#5272497)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's an older post, i'm trying to do some stuff on ipad. so if you have another one :).

Comment: simple googling give me this - http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-detect-pinch-in-iphone/

Comment: also check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448614/uiimageview-gestures-zoom-rotate-question

Comment: Thanks for links, but i really want to go in fullscreen mode instead of zooming!

Comment: means you want to remove navigation bar and tab bar?

Comment: i don't understand? suppose i have i UIImageView that contain my image, how can i move it to fullscreen with pinching in and back to original mode when pinching out. i'm i clear? this is my question.

Comment: There is no automatic method to do this.. you have to do it manually. when pinching you have to hide your navigation bar and tab bar manually and set the image's frame to screen size..

Comment: I posted code to hide navigation bar in answer and a link where you can find code to hide tab bar... Please check carefully!!

Comment: I think that you don't understand my question. my problem is how to pinch in => fullscreen, pinchout => normal size. i'm not intrested in tabbar i want to do this with UIGestureRecognizer if you have some ideas thanks. My problem is not the tabbar!